# JTable insertRow ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to insert a row to my table after the click of a button, but I am receiving the stack exception below.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.justifyRows(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(Unknown Source)
    at com.testingarea.TestModel$2.actionPerformed(TestModel.java:64)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've created the SSCCE below so you can re-create. I'm not entirely sure why this happens, I think it may have something to do with my model?

```
package com.testingarea;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestModel {

  private DespatchTypeParameterTableModel _model = new DespatchTypeParameterTableModel();
  private JTable _table = new JTable(_model);

  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }

    });
  }

  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new TestModel().makeUI());
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private Component makeUI() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(_table), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return p;
  }

  private Component createButtonPanel() {
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));
    JButton insertButton = new JButton("Insert Despatch Type Parameter");
    insertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int lastSelectedRow = _table.getSelectionModel().getMaxSelectionIndex();
        int realRow = lastSelectedRow;
        Vector vector = new Vector();
        _table.clearSelection();
        if (lastSelectedRow == -1) {
          ((DefaultTableModel)_model).insertRow(_table.getRowCount(), vector);
          _model.addDespatchTypeParameter(new DespatchTypeParameter("Test Name", "Test Description", "Test Value"));
          _table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(_table.getRowCount() - 1,
            _table.getRowCount() - 1);
        } else {
          ((DefaultTableModel)_model).insertRow(realRow + 1, vector);
          _model.addDespatchTypeParameter(new DespatchTypeParameter("Test Name", "Test Description", "Test Value"));
          _table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(realRow + 1, realRow + 1);
        }
      }

    });
    buttonPanel.add(insertButton);
    return buttonPanel;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  private static final class DespatchTypeParameterTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private Vector<DespatchTypeParameter> _dtParameterList;

    public DespatchTypeParameterTableModel() {
      setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"Parameter Name", "Parameter Description", "Parameter Value"});
      _dtParameterList = new Vector<DespatchTypeParameter>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
      return _dtParameterList == null ? 0 : _dtParameterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
      Object value = null;
      DespatchTypeParameter dtParameter = getDespatchTypeParameter(row);
      if (getColumnName(column).equals("Parameter Name")){
        value = dtParameter.getParameterName();
      }else if (getColumnName(column).equals("Parameter Description")){
        value = dtParameter.getParameterDescription();
      }else if (getColumnName(column).equals("Parameter Value")){
        value = dtParameter.getParameterValue();
      }
      return value;
    }

    public DespatchTypeParameter getDespatchTypeParameter(int row){
      if (row < 0 || row >= _dtParameterList.size()){
        return null;
      }
      return (DespatchTypeParameter)_dtParameterList.get(row);
    }

    public void addDespatchTypeParameter(DespatchTypeParameter despatchTypeParameter) {
      if (despatchTypeParameter != null){
        _dtParameterList.add(despatchTypeParameter);
        fireTableRowsInserted(_dtParameterList.size() - 1, _dtParameterList.size() - 1);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeRow(int row) {
      if (row >= 0 && row < _dtParameterList.size()){
        _dtParameterList.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public Vector<DespatchTypeParameter> getDataVector() {
      return _dtParameterList;
    }

  }

  private static class DespatchTypeParameter {
    private String _parameterName;
    private String _parameterDescription;
    private String _parameterValue;

    public DespatchTypeParameter(String parameterName, String parameterDescription, String parameterValue) {
      _parameterName = parameterName;
      _parameterDescription = parameterDescription;
      _parameterValue = parameterValue;
    }

    public String getParameterName() {
      return _parameterName;
    }

    public String getParameterDescription() {
      return _parameterDescription;
    }

    public String getParameterValue() {
      return _parameterValue;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: DefaultTableModel doesn't required duplicate call for fireTableRowsXxx, please did you tried this code without to override DefaultTableModel (I think that wrong), then must work, use addRow instead of insertRow (depends or result from if - else)

Comment: @mKorbel addRow gives me a similar out of bounds exception. I did the override as I had some bespoke behaviour I wanted to override with getValueAt etc.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed it by removing

```
   @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
      return _dtParameterList == null ? 0 : _dtParameterList.size();
    }
```